# Not allowed to return a result ? stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE TABLE ZAMOWIENIA( id_zamowienia INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    id_uzytkownika INT, kwota_zamowienia DECIMAL(10,2));

INSERT INTO
    ZAMOWIENIA VALUES (1,1,20), (2,4 ,5), (3,3,100), (4,1,300),
    (5,2,80), (6, 1,150);

SELECT * FROM ZAMOWIENIA;

select
    count(id_uzytkownika) from ZAMOWIENIA WHERE id_uzytkownika=1;

DROP
    FUNCTION AccountType;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION AccountType(
    in_id_uzytkownika INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
    DECLARE account_type VARCHAR(20); 
    DECLARE in_id_uzytkownika INT;
    DECLARE zamowienia INT;

    select count(id_uzytkownika)  AS zamowienia 
    from ZAMOWIENIA 
    WHERE id_uzytkownika=in_id_uzytkownika; 

    select zamowienia from zamowienia;

    IF zamowienia >10 THEN      
        SET account_type = 'BRONZE';
    END IF;      
    IF zamowienia >30 THEN      
        SET account_type = 'SILVER';
    END IF;     
    IF zamowienia >60 THEN      
        SET account_type = 'GOLD';
    END IF;

    return account_type; 
END // DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Where is stored procedure??? Look carefully, letter-by-letter: `CREATE FUNCTION AccountType ...`

Comment: You might try to word the question a little bit better and provide a little more detail. For example, How can I return a result from a stored procedure? My procedure is detailed here and I want to return <...>, but I get the error <...>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a variable to the result of a `SELECT` query, you need to use `SELECT ... INTO variable`, not `SELECT ... AS variable`.  Your function is trying to return the result of the `SELECT` query because it doesn't store the result into a variable.

Or you can use `SET` statement, which is simpler when you're just setting a single variable.

So replace the two `SELECT` statements with:

```
SET zamowienia = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM from ZAMOWIENIA 
    WHERE id_uzytkownika=in_id_uzytkownika);
```

Also, you shouldn't have `DECLARE` statements for the function parameters. Remove the line

```
DECLARE in_id_uzytkownika INT;
```

Comment: Your answer has helped me a lot :)